# Avoiding deployment gem-fail downtime while using Passenger, bundler & git-based deploys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger, capistrano, bundler

I'm deploying a Rails 3 app on Passenger 3.0.7 using capistrano and git-based deployment, similar to GitHub's setup:
https://github.com/blog/470-deployment-script-spring-cleaning -- this means the app operates entirely out of one directory, with no /releases/123456 and symlink switching.

If we've added any gems our app starts throwing 500 errors during deployment, during the "bundle:install" phase, but *before deploy:restart*. The code has been updated and it seems like passenger is already starting to use it, and required gems can't be found yet.

This is not caused by new workers being spun up, as I've tried setting the Passenger idle_time to 0 and max_instances and min_instances to the same value, so that workers are never spun down.

Running on Linux with ruby-ee 1.8.7-2011.03. Sample error from Passenger: https://gist.github.com/54794e85d2c799e4f697

I've also considered doing "two-directory" git-based deployment as a hack -- swapping in the new code once the bundle is complete. Ideas welcome.

Comment: I'm betting there is not really any decent solution besides the two-directory setup you mentioned; no matter what you tell Passenger, when a new worker is started, code will be read from your filesystem. If updating the Gemfile first doesn't cause this issue, you might give that a shot, but I'm guessing it'll fail just as badly.

Comment: So strangely this has nothing to do with starting new workers -- it affects existing workers too

Answer (score 0):

Go with the two-directory deployment. Apart from avoiding the 500s during deployment, this will also act as a safety net if you need to rollback during/after deployment.

Comment: I can rollback just fine using git-based deployments, and they are significantly faster than copying directories around all the time... but errors while bundling are much worse :(